# Knockout not rendering

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

**Scenario:**

I have a `ViewModel` that has the a list of `Grades` in it. I need to get Knockout to render those grades, just the names will be fine.

**Current Output:**

The data is being captured by the `ViewModel`. I know this because of a series of `console.log()` statements in my code that do return what I expect it to return.

**Expected Output:**

Just a series of `<p>` tags with the name of the grade in them.

**Links:**

Fiddle: **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CZLn4/1/)**

PasteBin: **[Here](http://pastebin.com/B7rE0wdt)**

**Current Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php 
        include "./includes/functions.php";
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/ko.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/ko-mapping.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load() {

            var parsedJSON = <?php echo json_encode(populateGrades()) ?>;
            console.log(parsedJSON);

            function Grade (id, name, springPressure) {
                this.id = ko.observable(id);
                this.name = ko.observable(name);
                this.springPressure = ko.observable(springPressure);
            }

            function ViewModel() {
                var self = this;

                self.grades = ko.utils.arrayMap(parsedJSON, function(item) {
                    return new Grade(item.id, item.name, item.springPressure);
                });

                console.log(self.grades);

                self.chosenGrade = ko.observable();

                self.json = ko.toJSON(self.grades);
            }

            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

        }
    </script>


</head>
<body onload="load()">
    <!--  ko foreach: grades -->
        <p data-bind="name"></p>
    <!--  /ko -->
</body>
</html>
```

Any feedback and or comments are always welcomed, and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty simple typo: the field names are wrong:

```
self.grades = ko.utils.arrayMap(parsedJSON, function (item) {
    return new Grade(item.GradeID, item.Name, item.SpringPressure);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CZLn4/2/

Comment: Thanks, just figured that out... Feel like such a chop.